# playbook に対しての変数を定義できますか？

Tags: ansible

playbook の中で一通して利用したい変数があります。これを定義する方法はありますか？
近い変数は、 set_fact/register による fact 的な情報の登録なのですが、これは

- (playbook,host) 単位に対して管理されるため、 playbook の中ですべての play で共通して使う変数としては使いづらい

と考えたので、質問しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inventory の全てのノード(host)が all グループに属するので、group_vars/all.yml に書けば目的のことができると思います。

inventory に書くなら

```
[web]
192.168.56.10

[db]
192.168.56.20

[all:vars]
ntp_server=192.168.56.1
```

group_vars/all.yml に書くなら

```
---
ntp_server : 192.168.56.1
```

もしくは、コマンドラインで指定する。--extra-vars も playbook 全体(global)になります。

Variable Scopes
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes

Comment: playbook の中で…ってことだと難しいですね。うーん。